# tensorflow object detection from image not from live Camera

Tags: android, image, tensorflow-lite

Hi i want to try myself on object detection on Android in images not in live camera previews and i've seen that there is tensorflow lite. Sadly the tutorials i could find are all for live camera previews and not for images. So does anyone know about a tutorial or something for tensorflow lite or some other way to detect objects in images, that could teach me how to do basic object detection?Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think generally it's two steps:

1. Get image (no matter from preview or photos or anything), convert it to `android.graphics.Bitmap`
2. Do Object detection from `Bitmap`

The part (1) is more like an Android question. For (2), you could checkout [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/bef9fa3b8c81260decc925ced507739a5718c7ef/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L152)

Note: To use the `recognizeImage` method, you need to resize the `Bitmap` to `INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE` by your own, which is not obvious.